Insufficient mtl files generated when I export a wavefront.obj file from Blender
Working from Blender 4.0.2 here. I'm still pretty new at this.
When I have a model structure in Blender just how I like it, I try exporting it as a Wavefront.obj file. The shape exports fine, but the .mtl file is very small (4KB) as opposed to the 400 or so KB it probably should be, based on other applications I have used .obj format with. When I reimport the model, or attempt to import it into another application (Terragen in this case, an application I have only just started with) I get no textures at all. So... what am I missing? I've actually searched through a fair batch of other people's questions on similar problems, but those don't quite seem to apply to what's happening with me. Thanks for your attention...

The MTL files exported by blender do not pack the textures internally. However, the active textures should be exported to the same folder… You are using image textures, yes?

...the reason @TheLabCat is asking if you are using image textures is, if you do not know, that only image textures will be exported. No procedural textures like Noise, Musgrave, Voronoi, Checker, Brick etc. To use them you would have to bake them to get a UV mapped 2D image texture of them.

Yes, all image textures throughout. I'm running into another thing also... when I import an .obj object into Blender, and do a bunch of fixes and adjustments to the textures in Blender and then export a new .obj file, the new .obj does not open the textures properly, as though making changes to the textures discombobulated the outgoing .mtl file in such a way as to make it non-functional.
